Accessing the VPC endpoints in a shared subnet
I want to deploy a Databricks Workspace into a shared subnet from a participant account. The private link vpc endpoints for databricks have been deployed into the same subnet. According to this documentation: "You can't create, describe, modify, or delete VPC endpoints in subnets that are shared with you. However, you can use the VPC endpoints in subnets that are shared with you.", which i would understand as: I can't see the endpoints in the console, but as long as i have the ids of the vpc endpoints, i can use them. However, after deploying a new workspace into the shared subnets, i am not able to starta cluster, which is an indication, that private link does not work as intended. For deployment i use a pretty standard terraform setup, so i don't expect any issues coming from there. Can someone guide me to the correct setup of databricks with private link in shared subnets?

Have not done this but I would not expect you to have to know the Endpoint IDs of the VPC Endpoints. The client would learn the private IP address of an interface endpoint through DNS resolution of the target service, provided by Amazon's DNS service.

@jarmod thanks for your comment, but you need the id to register the endpoints in the databricks account. However, that is not the issue since i do have the ids, but databricks is, for some reason, not able to reach the endpoints.

Do you get any errors when you attempt to launch the Databricks cluster? It would launch the cluster via EC2 API endpoints on the Internet, without using network connectivity into the actual VPC. The VPC Endpoint would allow resources running in the cluster to access specific services -- it doesn't have anything to do with Databricks itself. What do you mean by "VPC Endpoints for Databricks"?
